# Animating along a path with some rotation?

Tags: animation, constraints

I've got a "flubber" like character model. I'm trying to animate the model along a path and add a playful rotation of the model at certain points along the path. I've successfully animated the character along the path using the 2 most common methods (a) parenting method (b) follow path constraint.

Ideally when the model descends at a point I would like to have a 360 degree spin, but Blender doesn't retain the keyframes I've placed. Is there solution for this?

Comment: How exactly are you rotating and keyframing it? (this should be working). If you rotate with `R` the rotation will be normalized, which would make it appear as if nothing happened. If that is what's happening, try animating from the properties region (`N`) instead.

Comment: I set a keyframe (I) at the start of where I want a spin and then set a keyframe (I) at the end of the spin. I use the Transform panel (n) to make my adjustments

Comment: You can if none of the other solutions work, parent an empty to the curve then parent the object to the empty.

Comment: That's how I have it currently configured.

Comment: Update: I've parented the Empty to the BezierCurve using "Path Constrain" and I have "follow" checked on in the path animation of the curve. I've been successful in adding some keyframes that start a rotation, but they are acting really weird.

Comment: Apparently the order in how you set the keyframe is MAJOR. I would set the keyframes then make my adjustments in the transform panel. From what I've seen  in the past half hour it's best to make your transformations then set a keyframe. If you want to adjust a keyframe, then you use the graph editor.

Comment: @user5071 When you set a keyframe, it stores the current transform values for that frame. If you make any changes after that you will have to set the keyframe again, since it doesn't auto update.

Comment: You can use Ctrl-T on a curve point to 'rotate' the point, the object following the path will also follow this rotation.